# How to use data binding to change part of class name string to any ISO country code?

Tags: css, angular, data-binding

I want to display the country flag icon of an element using the [flag-icon](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css) stylesheet. This displays a country flag based on a country's ISO code, for example:

```
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gr"></span>
```

Displays the Greek flag (ISO code GR).

How do I dynamically change the two-character ISO code? Something like this:

```
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{un_country}}"></span>
```

Or this:

```
<span [className]="'flag-icon flag-icon-{{un_country}}'"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems `class="flag-icon" [ngClass]="'flag-icon-' + un_country"` should work

Answer (score 0):

in **comp.html**

`class="flag-icon" [ngClass]="flagClass"`

in **comp.ts**

`this.flagClass='flag-icon-' + this.un_country;`